# Can I access the request object in a console error?

Tags: python, django, logging

I am not very familiar with Django but have to make some changes to how it logs for a project. I am wanting to add information from the request object to the logs.

```py
import logging

MODULE_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class IndexPage():

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    MODULE_LOGGER.warning("log me!")
    # code...
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

This then gets logged out by this class:

```py
import json
from fluent import handler

class JsonFormatter(handler.FluentRecordFormatter):
    def format(self, record):
        data = super(JsonFormatter, self).format(record)
        return json.dumps(data)
```

And we have the following logger settings (which I don't really understand)

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "root": {"level": "WARNING", "handlers": ["sentry", "json_console"]},
    "formatters": {
        "console": {"datefmt": syslog_date_fmt, "format": syslog_msg_format},
        "json_fmt": {
            "()": "out_project.logs.JsonFormatter",
            "format": {
                "level": "%(levelname)s",
                "hostname": "%(hostname)s",
                "name": "%(name)s",
                "where": "%(module)s.%(funcName)s",
                "stack_trace": "%(exc_text)s",
            },
        },
    },
    "filters": {
        "require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"},
        "file_logging": {"": ""},
    },
    "handlers": {
        "null": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.NullHandler",
        },
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "console",
        },
        "sentry": {
            "level": "WARNING",
            "class": "raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler",
        },
        "json_console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "json_fmt",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "raven": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["json_console"],
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "sentry.errors": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["json_console"],
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "out_project": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": True,
        },
    },
}
```

The Django docs talk about a `django.request` logger, however this seems to be when there is an issue with the request (say 4XX, 5XX error). I have tried adding this logger with its handlers being the `json_console` handler however it the `request` object doesn't appear on the `record` object.

Ideally I am looking to add data from the request object to the record, or for it to be automatically put there. I am assuming once it is there, I can then change how the log looks by updating the `json_fmt.format` property.

From what I understand I can add additional information to the individual logs, however the data I am wanting to get from the request needs to be added to every log that is done via the logger from `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

I am very new to how logging works in Django so apologies if I have explained or understood something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the pip package [django-middleware-global-request](https://pypi.org/project/django-middleware-global-request/). I can import this anywhere and use the request object its method `get_request`.

```py
from django_middleware_global_request.middleware import get_request


class JsonFormatter(handler.FluentRecordFormatter):

  def format(self, record):
    def add_request_data(data):
    request = get_request()
    if request:
      # do stuff with request and data
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug the error use `breakpoint()`, this way you will get an interactive console where you can type in the variable and see its value.

If you want to log the request object modify your `JsonFormatter` like this

```
class JsonFormatter(handler.FluentRecordFormatter):

    def format(self, record):

        if type(record) in [str]:
            data = super(JsonFormatter, self).format(record)

        else:
            # request object | manually serialize it
            request_data = f"{request.status} | {request.user.username} | {request.data} | ... other request data"
            data = super(JsonFormatter, self).format(request_data)

        return json.dumps(data)
```

Now in your views.py for `IndexPage`:

```
class IndexPage():

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
        MODULE_LOGGER.warning(request)
        # code...
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the request object automatically given to the logger? Can this be maybe solved by having another layer to handle the log functionality?

Comment: yes, you can write a Mixin class to do the same... and inherit it in the views layer

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example of what this mixin could look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to know more about logger you need to check Python documentation, it's not related to Django. Django uses a JSON to configure Python loggers. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

To have request inside each log, you can go the explicit way, i.e. replace all

```
MODULE_LOGGER.warning("log me!")
```

with

```
MODULE_LOGGER.warning("log me!", extra={"request": request})
```

then inside your formatter you'll have the request object

```
class JsonFormatter(handler.FluentRecordFormatter):
    def format(self, record):
        print(record.request) # Probably you want to do something more useful here.
        data = super(JsonFormatter, self).format(record)
        return json.dumps(data)
```

If this doesn't suit you and you want to **automatically and implicitly** pass request to your logger, then you need to do something more complex like a middleware. Most of time Django is deployed using a thread/process based servers, so current thread is handling one request at a time. So we can store current request object in a thread local storage (with a middleware), and pick it up in our logger.

Add this, let say in file "my_pretty_middleware.py"

```
import threading

_local = threading.local()
_local.current_request = None


class StoreRequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        try:
            _local.current_request = request
            return self.get_response(request)
        finally:
            _local.current_request = None


def get_current_request():
    return _local.current_request
```

Then add this middleware at top of your middlewares. Like

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "my_pretty_middleware.StoreRequestMiddleware"
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

Then in your formatter (or whatever part of code), you can get the request object.

```
from my_pretty_middleware import get_current_request


class JsonFormatter(handler.FluentRecordFormatter):
    def format(self, record):
        request = get_current_request()
        if request:  # Beware it can be None in case you're logging outside of request cycle.
            print(request)  # Probably you'd like to do something else
        data = super(JsonFormatter, self).format(record)
        return json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

check and install requestLogging.

it helps you modify and format your logs with the request object.